# HTTP/HTTPS traffic failing except when on mobile

Tags: networking

My issue is that I am only able to access https://healthcheck-r-failover.cododigital.co.uk on my mobile phone. BrowserStack, my own PC and my monitoring are all unable to access.

This domain has an A record to 45.148.166.157. I am able to access http://45.148.166.157/ and https://45.148.166.157/ on my mobile, but not on any of other devices.

The domain itself points to port 8693, so http://45.148.166.157:8693 and http://healthcheck-r-failover.cododigital.co.uk are the same. Note this port doesn't accept HTTPS.

This issue started at 8:20 this morning, I'm perplexed at what the reason is.

Comment: Works fine here. Can you [edit] and include `pathping` (or `tracert`) output?

Comment: Thank you @DavidPostill, I've just restarted the router which seems to have done the trick (even though I'd restarted the router 10 mins after this issues started)

Answer (score 0):

It seems restarting the router through the GUI (instead of flicking the switch) helped